# Building errors with the Matrix Template Library 2 and g++ 4.7

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, 64-bit, debian, g++-4.7

A few years ago I had to use the `MTL 2` library in my career's final project (it was a mandatory requirement). I had to work on an existing (and rather old) code and the compiler I used was `g++ 4.4`.

Now, I want to keep working on that project to try and improve it. I want to use some `C++11` features and since `Debian Wheezy` comes with `g++ 4.7`, I think I'll use it.

So, I installed `MTL 2` and tried to compile the project. But I got an error reagarding `ptrdiff_t` was not known:

```
error: expected type-specifier before ‘ptrdiff_t’
error: expected ‘>’ before ‘ptrdiff_t’
error: template argument 4 is invalid
```

Googleing a bit I found that since `g++ 4.6` some things changed in the standard headers and that I needed to include the `cstddef` header in order to make `ptrdiff_t` known **(a)**.

So I included that header into the `MTL 2` files that used `ptrdiff_t` and recompiled the project. However, a new error appeared:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/mtl/matrix.h:41:0,
             from /usr/local/include/mtl/mtl2lapack.h:20,
             from MCl_Eigen.cpp:36:
/usr/local/include/mtl/envelope2D.h:72:20: error: declaration of ‘typedef struct mtl::twod_tag mtl::envelope2D<T>::dimension’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/local/include/mtl/matrix_implementation.h:25:0,
             from /usr/local/include/mtl/matrix.h:33,
             from /usr/local/include/mtl/mtl2lapack.h:20,
             from MCl_Eigen.cpp:36:
/usr/local/include/mtl/dimension.h:19:7: error: changes meaning of ‘dimension’ from ‘class mtl::dimension<typename mtl::dense1D<T>::size_type>’ [-fpermissive]
make: *** [MCl_Eigen.o] Error 1
```

My question is if there's a way to use `MTL 2` with the `g++ 4.7` compiler or is it better to use a newer version and adapt the code to it? (or use the same compiler as before, `g++ 4.4`)

**(a)** I included the `cstddef` header directly into the `MTL` files. Should I have done it in the project files instead?

Comment: That version of Debian comes with GCC 4.6. Maybe try that first.

Comment: Hi! I'll try it for sure. But if possible, I would like to use the latest version to have available the most resources from `C++11`. Anyway, I'll try with `g++ 4.6`

Comment: @Tshepang I tried with `g++ 4.6` and nothing. The same error. With `g++ 4.4` went well, though. Isn't there any way to use the new features of `C++11` with an old `MTL` version? Using `MTL 4` it's a bit difficult, since I'll have to iterate through the project's source code and modify it to match the new version. For example, a header present in `MTL 2` is nowhere to be found in the new version. And that is an easy problem, I fear.

Comment: I am not familiar with MTL. May I suggest you start a Bounty on this question. Either that or ask on [C++ chat room](https://gist.github.com/tshepang/6134249). It's the most active room on SE AFAIK.

Comment: Ok!! Thanks! I'll ask in the chatroom!